# Create a column from 2 columns of 2 different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE OrderLine (
    OrderID int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Orders(OrderID),
    RewardID int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Rewards(RewardID),
    LineTotal int,
    Quantity int
)
```

```
CREATE TABLE Rewards (
    RewardID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    RewardName varchar(50),
    RewardDesc varchar(255),
    Price int
)
```

I have these 2 tables. What I want is that `LineTotal` is equal to `Quantity*Price`.
I know that if I have `Price` in my OrderLine I could do `LineTotal as ([quantity]*[price])`. But that's not what I want. I also read something about triggers but it wouldn't work due to errors.
What I tried

```
CREATE TRIGGER linetotal_insert
ON OrderLine   
FOR INSERT OrderLine.LineTotal = orderLine.Quantity*Rewards.Price
```

I use SQL Server 2018

Comment: Why use a trigger?  Why not just calculate this when you query the table?

Comment: I would suggest to handle this in the process of populating OrderLine with data (ETL... maybe SSIS?). However you should be able to fix this with a trigger as well, but this would require a little more code than the one you provided... you would need a join between inserted.RewardID and Rewards.RewardID

Comment: @Tyron78 Okay thank you, I have never used triggers before. So I was trying what i saw on the internet

Comment: @GordonLinoff It's for educational purpose and I want to learn how to do it and if it's possible

Comment: There is no SQL Server **2018** version - we have 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017 and 2019 - take your pick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example for a Trigger - however, this might fir the current requirement, but you should get familiar with further possibilities of SQL Triggers (such as handling inserts and updates differently in case quantity in OrderLine changes or even in case the price in Rewards changes):

```
CREATE TABLE OrderLine (
    OrderID int NOT NULL ,
    RewardID int NOT NULL,
    LineTotal int,
    Quantity int
)
GO

CREATE TABLE Rewards (
      RewardID int NOT NULL,
    RewardName varchar(50),
    RewardDesc varchar(255),
    Price int
)
GO

CREATE TRIGGER T1
ON OrderLine
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO OrderLine
  SELECT i.OrderID, i.RewardID, i.Quantity * ISNULL(r.Price, 0), i.Quantity
    FROM inserted i
    LEFT JOIN Rewards AS r ON r.RewardID = i.RewardID
END
GO

CREATE TRIGGER T2
ON OrderLine
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
  IF(UPDATE(Quantity)) 
  BEGIN
    UPDATE o
      SET LineTotal = ISNULL(r.price, 0) * i.quantity, o.Quantity = i.Quantity
      FROM inserted i
      JOIN Orderline o ON o.OrderID = i.OrderID
      LEFT JOIN Rewards r ON r.RewardID = i.RewardID
  END
END
GO
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0a4a9/1/4